# R Calculate Regular Intervals for Groups

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataset which contains GPS location data collected at random intervals (1-30s between each sample) and this data is collected for a number of individuals and on a few different days.

What I would like to do is create regular time intervals for my data which would mean discarding excess samples and potentially generating samples through linear interpolations.

I have found that there exists the cut() function but this takes all the records in a dataframe and breaks them into same size intervals, rather than same timeframe intervals. I'm also trying to do this for each individual so that I can end up with regular intervals of data for each person and for each day.

```
# Using cut breaks it into same size chunks, not based on time
intervalDF1 = DF %>%
  group_by(interval = cut(time, breaks = '10 sec'))

# Using seq gives a new vector of all intervals but doesn't transform the data
intervalDF2 <- seq(from = 0, to = max(entityState$time), by = 10)
```

The expected outcome would be to take these random samples for any given individual on any given day and to end up with interpolated samples every 10s seconds. Does anyone know a good way to do this in R and preferably with dplyr?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is down-sampling, which is not what `cut` is for. One way you may do this is to use the `seq` function based on the `range(..)` of time, and then `approx`imate your other columns (lat, lon, elev, etc); while those functions I just listed should be enough (I do downsampling of GPS-based telemetry regularly), there are some packages that might help if you prefer, though I've not found any of them to be worth the package-dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use my `{santoku}` package:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(santoku)

x <- Sys.time() + 1:20
chop_width(x, seconds(5), labels = lbl_dash(fmt = "%M:%S"))
 [1] 14:01—14:06 14:01—14:06 14:01—14:06 14:01—14:06 14:01—14:06 14:06—14:11
 [7] 14:06—14:11 14:06—14:11 14:06—14:11 14:06—14:11 14:11—14:16 14:11—14:16
[13] 14:11—14:16 14:11—14:16 14:11—14:16 14:16—14:21 14:16—14:21 14:16—14:21
[19] 14:16—14:21 14:16—14:21
Levels: 14:01—14:06 14:06—14:11 14:11—14:16 14:16—14:21
```